Integrating OpenCV with FastAPI and Redis RQ Causes Task/Job Failures
I'm working on integrating a set of microservices into our application, focusing on a FastAPI server that interacts with Redis through RQ for task queueing. The setup involves three main files:

server.py: Defines FastAPI endpoints.
redis_processes.py: Manages Redis connections and queues tasks.
worker_tasks.py: Contains the tasks to be enqueued and executed by workers.

The flow is as follows: The FastAPI endpoint receives some inputs and queues jobs in Redis. These jobs are defined in 'worker_tasks.py' and are supposed to be processed by background workers.
However, I'm encountering a peculiar issue: whenever I import 'cv2' (OpenCV) into 'worker_tasks.py', and I receive the following error message: "Work-horse terminated unexpectedly; waitpid returned 6 (signal 6).", but not on terminal though. This problem seems to be specifically related to the inclusion of the OpenCV library in 'worker_tasks.py'.
Here's a simplified version of the code for each component:
'server.py' snippet:
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile, File, Query, HTTPException, Security, Depends
from fastapi.security import HTTPBearer, HTTPAuthorizationCredentials
from typing import List, Optional
from models import FeedbackTask
import redis_processes

app = FastAPI()
security = HTTPBearer()

# Endpoint and authentication details omitted for brevity
@app.post("/processfeedback/")
async def process_feedback(...): # parameters and processing
    return redis_processes.process_feedback(feedback_task)


'redis_processes.py' snippet:
import redis
from rq import Queue
from redis_settings import workers_settings

import threading

import time
from datetime import datetime

from models import FeedbackTask
import worker_tasks as worker_tasks



# Set up Redis connection
redis_conn = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)

ai_task_processor_q         = Queue(name= workers_settings[0]['q'],connection=redis_conn)
initial_db_writer_q         = Queue(name= workers_settings[1]['q'],connection=redis_conn)
ai_task_result_writer_q     = Queue(name= workers_settings[2]['q'],connection=redis_conn)


def process_feedback(feedback_process_task: FeedbackTask):
    # tasks.process_feedback(feedback_task)
    now = datetime.now()
    timestamp = int(time.mktime(now.timetuple()))
    feedback_process_task.collection_id = f"{feedback_process_task.user_id}_{timestamp}"

    job_db_w = initial_db_writer_q.enqueue(worker_tasks.add_raw_collection_to_db, feedback_process_task, result_ttl=-1)
    job_ai   = ai_task_processor_q.enqueue(worker_tasks.process_feedback, feedback_process_task, result_ttl=-1)

    # return {"job_id": job_ai.get_id()}
    return {"AI Feedback Process Job Status": job_ai.get_status(),
            "Raw Document Collection Write Status": job_db_w.get_status()}

'worker_tasks.py' snippet:
import cv2  # This import causes the issue
from models import FeedbackTask

def process_feedback(task: FeedbackTask) -> FeedbackTask:
    # Task processing logic here


The tasks fail only after adding 'import cv2' in 'worker_tasks.py'. I've verified that the tasks work as expected when this import is commented out. My initial guess was it might be a problem with worker environments or a conflict between libraries, but I haven't found conclusive evidence to pinpoint the issue.
Has anyone faced a similar issue or does anyone have insights on why importing OpenCV in a worker task could lead to job failures in this setup? Any suggestions on how to debug or resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
If you would like to replicate the issue, please following the following link.

sounds like a broken environment or this "task" execution model does weird things.

I don't think there is an issue with environment as I tried to uninstall/install OpenCV. What would be your suggestions? I included the overall workflow to make the code replicable. I think this issue is somewhat similar to this one on reddit link.
I am using python 3.9.18, and here is the link for the requirement.txt link.

file a bug with whatever is responsible for this tasking. let them debug it. that means redis/fastapi/rq, not opencv.

I don't think it is something related to FastAPI, but rather RQ/Redis/OpenCV. I raised the issue in these report and will update the outcome here.

Context: issue on opencv/opencv, issue on rq/rq, issue on redis/redis-py
